# How to remove %20 from the file path?

Tags: python, filepath

```
file:///home/ashu/Music/Collections/randomPicks/ipod%20on%20sep%2009/Coldplay-Sparks.mp3
```

How can I convert a string like the above to get the normal file path which I can pass to `open()` function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at [`url2pathname`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.url2pathname):

```
import urllib2

path = urllib2.url2pathname("file:///home/ashu/Music/Collections/randomPicks/ipod%20on%20sep%2009/Coldplay-Sparks.mp3")
```

Answer (score 10):

This is called unquote. Avaiable from urllib.

```
import urllib
urllib.unquote('%20')
```